# How do I call upon checkboxes with groupname or tag?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, groupname

Am creating a form in which the user will be able to select 4 checkboxes. Blue, Green, Yellow, Red. They have to do this atleast twice, up to 5 times in total.

[The Form Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PekqB.png)

The first checkboxes are on the form, the other 4 grouped checkboxes are on multipages.

I've tried giving them a group name "Reeks" to "Reeks4", to then print their values into a single cell separated by comma.

The code I've found so far does print the values neatly, however, it grabs every available checkbox on my form instead of just from the group "Reeks".

The ways I've tried to add the groupname (or tag, named them both the same) to the code, only gives me errors.

```
For Each Control In Me.Controls
   If TypeName(Control) = "CheckBox" Then
               'If Control.GroupName = "Reeks" Then
                If Control.Value Then 
            Reeks = IIf(Reeks <> "", Reeks & ", ", "") & Control.Caption
        End If
        End If
    Next
```

```
With ws 
.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Reeks
End With
```

Any help is welcome, but if at all possible please add comments as I only started on VBA last week.

(Side note. I also have framed checkboxes on the multipages in which the user can select the location of said colour. Side + Top view. Which will need to work the same as with the colours, but printed in different columns. )

Comment: You can look at the `parent` of the control, whether it the userform or the multipage page.  Or reference deeper, so instead of `me.controls` use `Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls`

Comment: Exchanging me.controls for Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls solved my issues with the multipages, and prints Reeks1 to Reeks4 as requested. How do I adress the original Reeks parent?

Comment: How do you mean the original reeks parent?

Comment: The orginal 'Reeks' is placed above/outside of the Multipage menu. I copy pasted 4 Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0 to 3).Controls bits of code which take their info from their individual Reeks1(to4). But Reeks still has Me.Controls which claims the input from the multipages still. 

I tried Me.Userform.Controls, Me.Userform.Reeks.Controls, but VBA says no to those.

Comment: Use the `.parent` then from `me.controls` so say `if ctl.parent="UserForm1" then ` and base on that, or `select case ctl.parent`

Comment: Sorry, I dont fully understand .parent/ctl/select case yet,  is it possible to show me a sample of how it should look? I added a sample image of my form, am now finding Me.Multipage gives me the same issues when trying to define just the first colours and not also the Frame locations.

Comment: `if control.parent="UserForm1" then strX="Reeks" else <<do your string bit here>> end if`  also avoid using keywords like `control` for your variable names, this can get confusing.  Use something like `for each ctl in me.controls`

Comment: Thank you for your patience & help. Your comments helped me a lot, your last suggestion gave me another error (450). However I found the solution by changing the 'comment line to If ctl.Object.Groupname = "Reeks" Then. And now it seems to be working!